# Webdriver-manager is not working on python exe

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, exe, webdriver-manager

**I have a small python script:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from tkinter import *


def go_google():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://google.com")


google = Tk()
google.geometry("800x500")
Button(google, text="Google", font="Helvetica 12 bold", command=go_google).pack(pady=200)
google.mainloop()
```

I want to convert it to exe. So I'm using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w script.exe
```

But the exe file is not working properly. When I'm clicking the `Google` button its not going google.com

***Note:*** When I'm using `pyinstaller --onefile script.exe` this command for create the exe file then the exe file is working properly. But here a console opening. I need without console.

**What can I do now?**

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: if Your code uses the console You can't just not use it, also if you create a shortcut for that exe, then I think it is possible to somewhat hide the console

Comment: Should be fixed in version 3.5.0 webdriver_manager released yesterday. @Jawad Please update and check again.